# Character and monster buffing

Tags: munchkin

Let's say someone draws a monster face up when they kick open the door.  They are able to defeat the monster, but another play throws down a card to buff the monster.  The person who kicked open the door counters.  Now someone else buffs the monster.  This repeats until everyone runs out of cards.  What is the general rule for this situation?  Can it keep going or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can keep on going until nobody can/wants to throw any more cards. As seen in the rules(example, p. 5):

> ### Example of Combat, With Numbers and Everything
>
> Aric is a 4th-Level Warrior with the Chainsaw of Bloody Dismemberment
>   (which gives him a +3 to his combat strength). He kicks open the door
>   and finds the Net Troll, a Level 10 monster. Aric’s at a 7, the Net
>   Troll is at a 10, so Aric is losing.
>
> *Aric*: I was hoping to save this
>   card . . .
>
> **He plays the Magic Missile, giving him +5 for this fight. Now his combat strength is 12, beating the Net Troll’s 10.**
>
> *Aric*: Ha! Net Troll going down!
>
> *Suzan*: Not so fast. Now he’s Enraged.
>
> **Suzan plays Enraged, adding 5 to the Net Troll’s combat strength. Now Aric
>   is losing, 15 to 12.**
>
> *Aric*: Curses!
>
> *Suzan*: Want some help? *(Suzan is playing a Level 2 Elf with the Boots of Butt-Kicking, so her combat
>   strength is 4. Combined with Aric’s 12, they would have 16, enough to
>   defeat the Net Troll’s 15.)*
>
> *Aric*: And give you a level? Not a chance! I’m Berserking.
>
> **Aric uses his Warrior power and discards three cards:
>   Thief and a Wandering Monster from his hand, and Yuppie Water (usable
>   only to help an Elf) from his carried items. Each one gives him +1 to
>   his combat strength.**
>
> *Suzan*: Not the Yuppie Water! Noooo . . .
>
> *Aric*: That’s +3 to me, and now we’re tied, 15 to 15. Because I’m a Warrior,
>   I win ties . . . so I’m killing the Net Troll unless someone else
>   plans to mess with me. Anyone?
>
> **No one says anything, so Aric goes up a
>   level and claims the Net Troll’s treasures – three from the Net Troll
>   card, and one extra because it was Enraged. And the game goes on . . .**

As you see, you can cast any number of spells during combat.

Comment: Should the rule of 2.6 seconds be applied in between each throw down.  We accidentally let a round go for 10 minutes trying to figure out who was buffing what.

Comment: @Jeebwise 2-6 second rule is just a rule that basically means that you should let other players play something before claiming your level(s) and treasure(s). So if player A is fighting a monster, players B and C may buff the monster at the same time, player C doesn't have to wait 2-6 seconds after player B buffed the monster

Comment: @Jeebwise, You give 2.6s for people to say/do something when you ask "Anyone doing anything?" (I've always considered saying "Wait" to interrupt the timer.) It could come up multiple times in a combat (i.e. whenever you are winning).

Comment: Lol, we normally wait until level 8/9 to become really nasty.  Last game, we had 3 players on level 9, and one on level 3. The last one eventually won ;-).

Comment: @ToonKrijthe I think everybody does that. Till level 8/9 people just level up and help each other. When somebody is at level 8 or 9(especially 9) he gets more troubles from other players than from monsters he or she encounters :)

Comment: The 2.6 second rule is a joke, Literally.See the official munchkin faq: http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq. "Q. My friends start counting 2.6 seconds as soon as they turn over a monster and combat begins. That's not even enough time to read the card! Is this legal? A. The rule says you must get "a reasonable time" to respond when another player is winning a fight...The "2.6 seconds" part of the rule is a joke; the intent is that you cannot hold up the game indefinitely just because someone else is winning." The spirit of the rule is not to filibuster the game, not to encourage second-counting.